# How do I call static Java method from DMN model (Drools Business Central)

Tags: java, drools, dmn

I am using Business Central version 7.40.0. When calling static Java method `std` from Drools Business Central DMN project/model, I'm getting following error:

```
DMN: Error compiling Java function 'stdev' on node 'stdev': Error resolving external function as defined by: function(val) external { java: { class: ""com.sample.StandardDeviation"", method signature: ""std(java.lang.Number)"" }}...
Error compiling the referenced FEEL expression
```

I have:

1. Created Maven jar with static Java method

```
package com.sample;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
    
public class StandardDeviation {
    
    public static BigDecimal std(Number val) {  
        return new BigDecimal(val.doubleValue() * 2);
    }
}
```

2. [Imported Jar as Artifacts to Drools Business Central](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g91ad.png),
3. [Added Dependency to DMN project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWvpA.png)
4. In my DMN model, I am calling static Java method inside 'stdev' BKM (business knowledge model) element. [BKM with class and method signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yAC7.png)

   - class: `"com.sample.StandardDeviation"`
   - method signature:   `"std(java.lang.Number)"`
5. Saving BKM/DMN or building the model gives above error

What could be the issue?
Am I doing anything incorrectly?
How to check the logs in Drools Business Central?

Comment: I assume this is the same as https://groups.google.com/g/drools-usage/c/__R71v3n9qM/m/q6ygDHNzBQAJ and I just want to let you know we are investigating this issue. For now it seems this might be related to validation, so if the model looks correct to you and deployment works, you could ignore the message for now.

Comment: Thank  you @tarilabs for looking into this issue. Yes, it's the same post. I'll check if deployment works, as I stopped when I couldn't get past this issue.

Comment: You're right. Deployment is working. Thank you :)

Comment: Had the exact same issue, almost spent half a day trying to figure out the root cause. Thank god i stumbled on this post. Thank you @tarilabs

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of this issue as it was reported at [DROOLS-5577](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-5577)

Workaround exists as discussed in separate forum and as detailed in the JIRA issue, which was later [confirmed](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-5577?focusedCommentId=14395844&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14395844) by OP as in:

> 1. Ignore this validation error (red popup) while Saving the DMN Model with the editor
> 2. Proceed to Deploy the KJAR BC Project as usual